# Is there a USB 3.0 docking station which works on quantal (12.10)?

Tags: 12.10, usb, hardware, docking

Modern ultrabooks and hybrids pack sufficient power to serve as development workstations. Still, 1920x1080 screen resolution fits much better to a 23'' than 13''. There is a range of USB 3.0 devices with HDMI which make docking possible on Windows.

However, googling for 'usb 3.0 docking station ubuntu' and variants produces no valid pointers. I can find questions like 'does X work with linux' on windows-mostly hardware forums, but they are mostly left unanswered.

Please provide an answer from hand-on experience or a link to a USB 3.0 device use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe there are none.  A detailed discussion lambasting Displaylink for lack of Linux driver is here: 
www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=1748&page=5

Answer (score 1):

You can try upgrading to the latest kernel which has DisplayLink drivers baked in.

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/06/linux-kernel-3-9-8-released-how-to-upgrade-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/

Just make sure you get the latest version which at the time of this posting is 3.10.10.  See this url for the latest kernel.

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/